# Google maps api v3 remove markers when dragstart

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have the following function. `geolocationService.getNearbyPeoples()` is a service that
fetch data from db.

```
function nearbyPeoples(meLat, meLng, map){
    geolocationService.getNearbyPeoples(meLat, meLng).then(function(response){
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var nearbyLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(response.data[i].lat, response.data[i].lng);
            var nearbyMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: nearbyLatLng,
                title: response.data[i].first_name
            }).setMap(map);
        };
    });
}
```

then when dragend a center marker (meMarker) will call the function above to show nearby markers

```
google.maps.event.addListener(meMarker, 'dragend', function() {
            nearbyPeoples(meMarker.position.lat(), meMarker.position.lng(), map);
        });
```

then I want to remove the previous markers in dragstart. The reason is to prevent duplicated
markers if meMarker is dragend same location.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(meMarker, 'dragstart', function() {

        });
```

But I have no idea how to remove or any better suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing markers, why not keep a list (object) of markers as they are added and use it to avoid duplicating a marker?  And/or use it to remove markers outside the bounds of the map view, if you must remove markers.